# bijection between a set and a set of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, group-isomorphism

Question: For any function $f : A → B$ define an explicit isomorphism between A and the graph $Γ_f ⊂ A×B$ the subset defined by the property that for each $a ∈ A$ there is exactly one pair $(a, b) ∈ Γ_f$ whose first coordinate is $a$

Would the function $$g: A \rightarrow \Gamma_f$$ $$x\mapsto(x,x)$$
work as an isomorphism in this case?

Part two: 
Define a natural function $Γ_f → B$. Is it necessarily injective? Is it necessarily surjective?

The function I have chosen to define is $$h:(a,b)\mapsto b$$

and it seems to me that it need not be the case that the map is injective given that for $ a_1,a_2 \in A$ and $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in \Gamma_f$ it could be the case that $b_1=b_2$ s.t. $$(a_1,b_1,)\neq(a_2,b_2)$$ $$h((a_1,b_1))=b_1=b_2=h((a_2,b_2))$$

and similarly I don't see why the map need be surjective given that each point in $\Gamma_f$, $(a,b)$ could map to a single $b\in B$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding part one, no, it wouldn't. One simple reason for this is, $g$ takes an element of $a$ and returns element of $A \times A$, not element of $A \times B$, moreover it doesn't depend on the original function $f$.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it doesn't depend on the function f?

Comment: would the function $x /mapsto (a,x)$ work?

Comment: @GwenDi what's $a$?

Comment: I'll add the rest of the answer when we walk through the first part, because it would be a spoiler.

Comment: Ok I'm thinking about this in terms of a vertical line on a plane. So I am trying to formalize a function that would take a given every a in A to coordinates of the form (c, a) where c would be a constant.

Comment: First of all, switch the order in your pair ($g$ is from $A$ to (a subset of) $A\times B$). Second of all, you still don't use the fact, that a function $f$ is given to you (and you nowhere use it). Instead of a vertical line, think of the graph of $f$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89501/discussion-between-gwen-di-and-enedil).